# Access violation read location 0x00000004 when sending calllback from C++ code to C# code

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-ce

I am developing a windows 8 phone application, in which I need to send callback event messages from C++ code to the UI code in C#. Below is the C# code in which I am creating the callback function and sending it's pointer to the C++ code. The C++ code can send asynchronous event messages to UI using this function pointer.

**C# Code**

```
public partial class MainPage
{
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public delegate void CallBack([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strParam);
        [DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void PerformActionWithCallBack(int x);

        void DemonstrateCallBack()
        {
            int x;
            CallBack callback_delegate = new CallBack(CallBackFunction);
            // Converting callback_delegate into a function pointer that can be
            // used in unmanaged code.
            IntPtr intptr_delegate = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback_delegate);

            //Getting the pointer into integer value and sending it to C++

            x = (int)intptr_delegate;

            testApp.PerformActionWithCallBack(x);
        }

        //CallBack function in which event messages will be received
        void CallBackFunction([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strParam)
        {
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
            {
                //Updating the text block with the received message
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyTextBlock.Text = strParam);
            }
            else
            {
                MyTextBlock.Text = "Update directly";
            }
        }
}
```

> Below is the C++ code which will send event messages to C#

```
//Callback function prototype
typedef void(__stdcall *PCallBack)(LPSTR s);
LPSTR cbMsg = NULL;

//Global instance callback function
PCallBack gUICallback;

void TestApp::PerformActionWithCallBack(int x)
{
    //Assigning the received calllback function pointer from C# to global function pointer
    gUICallback = (PCallBack)x;
}

//This function will send event messages to C#
void SendCallbackMsg()
{
    while(1)
    {
         cbMsg = "Hello";
         Sleep(100);
         gUICallback(cbMsg);
         cbMsg = "Hi";
         Sleep(100);
         gUICallback(cbMsg);
    }
 }
```

With this code I am able to get the event messages in C# succcessfully, But after sending 650-700 calllbacks my application gives access violation exception and after that nothing works. I am suspecting the way I am passing the function pointer from C# to C++ but not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, callback_delegate gets garbage-collected.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says

> You must manually keep the delegate from being collected by the garbage collector from managed code. The garbage collector does not track reference to unmanaged code.

Try this

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    private CallBack _callBackDelegate = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public delegate void CallBack([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strParam);
    [DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void PerformActionWithCallBack(int x);

    void DemonstrateCallBack()
    {
        _callBackDelegate = new CallBack(CallBackFunction);
        int x;

        // Converting _callBackDelegate  into a function pointer that can be
        // used in unmanaged code.
        IntPtr intptr_delegate = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_callBackDelegate );

        //Getting the pointer into integer value and sending it to C++

        x = (int)intptr_delegate;

        testApp.PerformActionWithCallBack(x);
    }

    //CallBack function in which event messages will be received
    void CallBackFunction([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strParam)
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
        {
            //Updating the text block with the received message
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyTextBlock.Text = strParam);
        }
        else
        {
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Update directly";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do like this I have to make the CallbackFunction static. Otherwise the initialization of CallBackDelegate by "new CallBack(CallBackFunction);" will returns error as "field initializer can not reference the non-static field/method". And if I make the CallbackFunction static then I am not able to access Dispatcher object inside CallbackFunction, it giives error as "An object reference is required for non-static field/methot". It looks like deadlock. Thankyou.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Sorry, i am not a C# programmer, so I've mistaken. You just have to initialize this variable in constructor or in `void DemonstrateCallback()` method so that it remains in class and isn't static. I've edited my answer and fixed that

Comment: Hats off V. Kravchenko, you have resolved my problem. It's working perfactly. A big thanks to you.